# Почему не отображается картинка в React native? (Android)

Tags: android, react-native

Только начала изучать React native, и возник вопрос, почему может не отображаться картинка на телефоне?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image } from 'react-native';

class Bananas extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    return (
      <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Bananas', () => Bananas);
```

У меня отображается просто белый экран, подключение к интернету есть и работает исправно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обернула Image во View - картинка начала отображаться.

Измененный код выглядит так:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, View } from 'react-native';

class Bananas extends Component {
  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg'
    };
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => Bananas);
```